# Not able to install any package on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, seeing dpkg: error processing package

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

I'm trying to install Python3 package which was required to upgrade it to 16.04 LTS and then 18.04 OS. I've come across several links to solve it, but found no luck. Implemented following steps to remove and reinstall -

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>
sudo apt-get remove <packagename>
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

However, seeing the same issues

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-gi is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8666 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
dpkg: error processing package cloud-init (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone guide me through ??

Comment: Upgrading ubuntu version is not recommended already, and you are trying to upgrade twice?

Comment: @unlut Yes. I want to upgrade it from 14.04 to 18.04. However, there is no direct way to do it. It should be done through 16.04 -> 18.04. Seems like there is no straightforward process

Comment: Which tutorial you tried to follow for upgrading from 14 to 16? As far as I remember a dist upgrade was enough to upgrade your ubuntu to next LTS, you did not need to setup python manually.

Comment: I tried https://www.ostechnix.com/upgrade-ubuntu-single-command/, but I stuck on do-release-upgrade command and gave me weird python version related error, which turned out to be the main issue I'm having currently

Comment: I don't know if server version of Ubuntu has any differences, maybe someone else has an idea.